# Python 3.6 Having an issue with Import and "none" showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to programming and I am having a tough time trying to understand what is going on. I am trying to import random and use it later in a function, but it is just returning 0, which I assume is just the original variable I set, and the function I want to use isn't being used or called correctly.

There is a none that shows up when I run this in the shell, and from what I have read, it means that I am returning nothing (or none) value from something. Or something to that regard.

When the program runs, the "What is number1 + number2 just shows up as 0 + 0. Now, I have checked my files, and random.py is there. I have tried import random in a few different spots to see if that was the issue. I've tried random, random.randomint and the one that is currently there.

I am fairly new to all this, and I feel like this is basic stuff that I should know by now, but I am having a hard time with it.

Here is the code:

```
import random

def main():

    counter = 0
    studentName = "NO NAME"
    averageRight = 0.0
    right = 0.0
    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0
    answer = 0.0
    studentName = inputNames(studentName)

    while counter < 10:
        getNumbers(number1, number2)
        answer = getAnswer(number1, number2, answer)
        right = checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right)
        counter = counter + 1

    averageRight = results(right, averageRight)
    displayInfo(right, averageRight, studentName)


def inputNames(studentName):
    studentName = input(print("Input your name: "))
    return studentName

def getNumbers(number1, number2):
    number1 = random.randrange(1, 500)
    number2 = random.randrange(1, 500)


def getAnswer(number1, number2, answer):
    print("What is the answer to the following equation?")
    print(number1)
    print("+")
    print(number2)
    answer = eval(input("What is the sum? "))
    return answer

def checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right):
    if answer == number1 + number2:
        print("Right")
        right = right + 1
    else:
        print("Wrong")
    return right

def results(right, averageRight):
    averageRight = right / 10
    return averageRight

def displayInfo(right, averageRight, studentName):
    print("Information for the student: ", studentName)
    print("The number right: ", right)
    print("The average right is: ", averageRight)

main()
```

Comment: `getNumbers()` doesn't have a `return` statement, and even if it did, the line `getNumbers(number1, number2)` in `main()` doesn't try to assign its return value to any variables.

Comment: (incidentally, `getNumbers()` doesn't need any arguments ... it doesn't need to know anything about previous values of `number1` and `number2`.

Comment: Side-note: Don't use `eval` here. Use `ast.literal_eval` for safety, or if the values should only be integers anyway, just use `int`.

Comment: You might find [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) useful to get your head around how variables, arguments etc. work in Python.

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

For your `None` issue, this line is the cause:

```
studentName = input(print("Input your name: "))
```

`print` returns `None`, and `input` takes an argument that is the string to prompt the user with. You almost certainly wanted:

```
studentName = input("Input your name: ")
```

letting `input` do the prompting work directly.

The reason you always see `What is 0 + 0?` is because this function is broken:

```
def getNumbers(number1, number2):
    number1 = random.randrange(1, 500)
    number2 = random.randrange(1, 500)
```

That assigns to the local names `number1` and `number2`, not global variables nor the local variables in your `main` method (Python arguments are not passed by reference in the C++ sense of call-by-reference; when you assign to a name, it rebinds it locally, it doesn't change the caller). Make it return the values:

```
def getNumbers():
    number1 = random.randrange(1, 500)
    number2 = random.randrange(1, 500)
    return number1, number2
```

and assign them in `main`, changing:

```
getNumbers(number1, number2)
```

to:

```
number1, number2 = getNumbers()
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. I can't believe I goofed on the input(print( thing. That's super basic. I should have figured I was missing the return on the function. The thing that gets me, is putting the variables in the main. All the lingo involved kinda throws me for a loop too. Thanks for helping me through this.